# String_Split using SQL to separate column by commas

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, split, pivot

I'm trying to split a string of text using the ','. The text in question is our `utm` parameters and looks something like this:

```
{\""medium\"":\""cpc\"",\""source\"":\""google\"",\""term\"":\""virtual cocktail making classes\"",\""campaign\"":\""virtual-events\""}
```

The idea is I end up with four columns: Medium, Source, Term and Campaign. Here's what I've tried so far but keep getting a syntax error near **APPLY**.

```
(SELECT  id, VALUE
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by id ORDER BY id) AS "RowNum"
FROM seodata
CROSS APPLY
string_split(utmparams,',')
)

SELECT id,
[1] AS "medium", [2] AS "source", [3] AS "term", [4] AS "campaign"
FROM NAME_CTE
PIVOT 
(max(VALUE) FOR RowNum IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 1):

It *looks like* you have JSON data. If so, I would recommend JSON functions rather then string functions:

```
select s.id, j.*
from seodata s
cross apply openjson(s.utmparams) with(
    medium   nvarchar(50),
    source   nvarchar(50),
    term     nvarchar(50),
    campaign nvarchar(50)
) j
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone else mentioned, there are probably better ways to handle json if that is in fact what you're doing. That being said, here's my solution just using cross apply, some replace functions, and pivot.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Table
CREATE TABLE #Table
(
SampleData VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES
('{\""medium\"":\""cpc\"",\""source\"":\""google\"",\""term\"":\""virtual cocktail making classes\"",\""campaign\"":\""virtual-events\""}')

SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
SampleData
,REPLACE(LEFT(value,CHARINDEX(':',value)-1),'{','') Col
,REPLACE(RIGHT(value,LEN(value) - CHARINDEX(':',value)),'}','') Value
FROM #Table
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(SampleData,'""',''),'\',''),',')
) z
PIVOT
(
MAX(Value)
FOR Col IN (medium, source, term, campaign)
) p
```